# Reprojection from WGS to Slovenian Gauss Kruger in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gpx, slovenia

I have gpx file (track) in WGS84 (EPSG: 4326) coordinate system from Garmin GPSMAP 62 which is right projected in BaseCamp and MapSource. When I save track as *.GPX and import it to QGIS and use Settings/Project properties/Coordinate Reference System/ and set as EPSG:3787 I get a wrong projected track (cca 300 m western of right position). 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

First, have you checked that the GPX **layer** has CRS EPSG:4326?

To see if your track is correct you can install openlayers plugin, and show your track on top of Google satellite or OpenStreetMap.

EPSG:3787 is ment for Slovenia, deprecated by EPSG since 2009 (look for change request EPSG::2009.015), and should be replaced by EPSG:3911 and 3912. These are incorporated in latest GDAL 1.9.2 coming with Qgis Master.

Check if your proj string is:

> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs

This might help you understand slovenian problems:

http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/proj/2009-May/004652.html

http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/proj/2009-March/004485.html

http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Similar-datum-transforms-for-MGI-differ-too-much-td3843773.html

http://www.spatial-analyst.net/wiki/index.php?title=MGI_/_Balkans_coordinate_systems

Maybe

> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=426.9,142.6,460.1,4.91,4.49,-12.42,17.1 +units=m +no_defs

fits better for you. Qgis Master offers EPSG:3912:

> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs