# Transforming data from Austria and Slovenia

Tags: coordinate-system, austria, slovenia

Can anyone help with fitting together these 2 shapefiles?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/saa9yp7ecg1qxh1/Grenzen.rar

Answer (score 5):

The best I can get is:

gem in EPSG:31259

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=16.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=750000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs
```

Obcine in EPSG:3912

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

which results in this picture:

[image]

but if you go into detail you will see that the common borders are digitized with different precision:

[image]

You will have to fix that by hand.

For a deeper explanation about the Austrian-Slovenian datum shift problems, see this topic: [Reprojection from WGS to Slovenian Gauss Kruger in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43402/reprojection-from-wgs-to-slovenian-gauss-kruger-in-qgis)

I made another test with the two valid parameter sets for Slovenia:

blue:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=426.9,142.6,460.1,4.91,4.49,-12.42,17.1 +units=m +no_defs
```

green:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

The difference is about 9 metres, and the Austrian data in red (identically with OSM border lines) is in the middle of both:

[image]