# QGIS - CRS setting for Slovenia national agency data

Tags: coordinate-system, slovenia

This is just a humble information to my (newbee) fellow slovenian users of QGIS regarding correct setting of CRS for our country. For data provided by slovene national agency (GURS ...), use CRS marked as **MGI 1901 / Slovene National Grid EPSG:3912** and data should project, export etc fine. I was quite lost some time and almost give up on QGIS as I had so many problems using wrong EPSG settings provided internally by QGIS supposed to be "Slovene national grid D40, SNG D96, EPSG:4765, EPSG:3794 etc". Hope it will work for you, too.

Comment: It's great that you're sharing your humble information! But as this is a **Question/Answer** forum, could you please edit what you wrote and turn it into a _question_ and then post the solution part as an _answer_? =)

Comment: Maybe add your answer to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43402/reprojection-from-wgs-to-slovenian-gauss-kruger-in-qgis or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82821/transformation-data-austria-slovenia which adress the same topic.

Comment: @Joseph - sure I can do that but what would that change? If someone will look for an answer on this matter, he/she will get info either way. @ Andrej - I find question you were answering few years ago quite specific (reprojection from wgs ...) and overlooked your hint at the end of writing. But you are right and I learn a lot reading links provided in your answer. In my post I just tried to be straightforward to basic problem that bother quite some users of QGIS arround me and prevent them from using sw.

Comment: @user29347 - That is just how StackExchange sites operate, otherwise your post may get flagged and closed which means nobody will be able to view your information.

Comment: @user29347 through my links, this topic gets linked to those older questions in the right-hand column at the top position. That's the best I can do for you and others searching for the same problem.